# Unity2D: Fixing colliding for inventory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal was to make my character pickup item on collider (2D) didn't work.

 So here is what I've tried:

Player Controller Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

public float moveSpeed = 2f;

public Inventory inventory;


void Start()
{

}

public bool isGrounded;
public LayerMask groundLayers;



void Update()
{

    // isgrounded?
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(new Vector2(transform.position.x - 
0.2f, transform.position.y - 0.2f),
        new Vector2(transform.position.x + 0.2f, transform.position.y - 
0.21f), groundLayers);
    Jump();
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
    transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
}

void Jump()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 
2.5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    IInventoryItem item = hit.collider.GetComponent<IInventoryItem>();
    if (item != null)
    {
        inventory.AddItem(item);
    }
}
}
```

HUD SCRIPT:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HUD : MonoBehaviour
{

public Inventory Inventory;


void Start ()
{
    Inventory.ItemAdded += InventoryScript_ItemAdded;
}

private void InventoryScript_ItemAdded(object sender, InventoryEventArgs 
e)
{
    Transform inventoryPanel = transform.Find("InventoryPanel");
    foreach(Transform slot in inventoryPanel)
    {
        // Border... Image
        Image image = slot.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();

        // We found empty slot!
        if (!image.enabled)
        {
            image.enabled = true;
            image.sprite = e.Item.Image;

            // Todo store a reference;


            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Inventory Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
private const int SLOTS = 7;

private List<IInventoryItem> mItems = new List<IInventoryItem>();

public event EventHandler<InventoryEventArgs> ItemAdded;

public void AddItem(IInventoryItem item)
{
    if(mItems.Count < SLOTS)
    {
        Collider collider = (item as MonoBehaviour).GetComponent<Collider> 
();
        if (collider.enabled)
        {
            collider.enabled = false;

            mItems.Add(item);

            item.OnPickup();


            if (ItemAdded != null)
            {
                ItemAdded(this, new InventoryEventArgs(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Inventory Item Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IInventoryItem
{
string Name { get;  }

Sprite Image { get;  }

void OnPickup();
}

public class InventoryEventArgs : EventArgs
{
public InventoryEventArgs(IInventoryItem item)
{
    Item = item;
}

public IInventoryItem Item;
}
```

Rock Script (The object):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rock : MonoBehaviour, IInventoryItem 
{
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return "Rock";
    }
}


public Sprite _Image = null;

public Sprite Image
{
    get
    {
        return _Image;
    }
}

public void OnPickup()
{
    // TODO: ADD LOGIC THAT WILL MAKE THE ROCK A 'WEAPON' TO CUT DOWN THE 
TREE
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

}
```

All of those scripts work, but whenever I join my game and Collide the player with the object (all 2d, 2D Box colliders, etc.) the character wont pick the item up and put it in it's inventory?
The scripts are referenced to each other.

What did I do wrong?

Physics 2D Screenshot:

[image: Physics2D]

Player inspector screenshot:

[image: Player]

Rock (Object that needs to join his inventory)

[image: Rock]

Comment: Dont post screenshots of code. Post the actual code. Anyone having the same problem in the future likely wont be able to find this post with search engines if you use screenshots. And it makes it really difficult to answer your question because we cant copy it and fix it, we'd have to type it all manually. You probably wont get much help if people have to manually type whats in your screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do **not** post images of code in your post. You will be much more likely to get help when you post the *actual text* of the code in your question post.

Comment: Don't know how your code works (especially due to like the two comments before me: Do not post images of code!) but maybe you should use [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) or [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)?

Comment: sorry for making a screenshot for the code. for some reason copying and pasting didn't work!

Comment: I will try @derHugo!

Comment: @DetectivePikachu sorry! changed it :)

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your [physics2d collision matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html)

and screenshots of the inspector with items/player selected showing the their layers and the collider2d component in the same screenshot

Comment: @Ruzihm added! I hope I gave the good information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you are mixing the syntax of two events to create one that doesn't exist. `void OnCollisionEnter2D(ControllerColliderHit hit)` is not a built-in event in Unity. You probably mean to use `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D hit)`:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D hit)
{
    IInventoryItem item = hit.collider.GetComponent<IInventoryItem>();
    if (item != null)
    {
        inventory.AddItem(item);
    }
}
```

Another thing is that `BoxCollider2D` does not inherit from `Collider`. So, in AddItem, you should look for a `Collider2D` component instead:

```
public void AddItem(IInventoryItem item)
{
    if(mItems.Count < SLOTS)
    {
        Collider2D collider = (item as MonoBehaviour).GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        if (collider.enabled)
        {
            collider.enabled = false;

            mItems.Add(item);

            item.OnPickup();


            if (ItemAdded != null)
            {
                ItemAdded(this, new InventoryEventArgs(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consider this to be a partial solution because this may not capture all the changes needed... Let me know if this alone doesn't fix the problem in the comments below.

Comment: This helped me alot more! Now I get this message: There is no 'COllider' Attached to the "Rock" game object, but a script is trying to access it. you probably need to add a Collider to the game object "rock" or your script needs to check if the components is attached before using it.     I already attached 2D Box Collider to the rock

Comment: Your code doesn't show `COllider` being used as your comment mentions, but your comment varies between `Collider` and `COllider`, so it seems that you just made a typo. Please just paste the whole error as it appears in the log, especially the part that includes where the error occurred.

Comment: Sorry made a typo in the reaction! I will paste it here: 
     MissingComponentException: There is no 'Collider' attached to the "Rock" 
     game object, but a script is trying to access it.
     You probably need to add a Collider to the game object "Rock". Or your script 
     needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
    Inventory.AddItem (IInventoryItem item) (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:19)
    PlayerController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D hit) (at 
    Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:47). <br> this highlighted the player in unity Hierachy.

Comment: @Cypher thanks! I've edited this answer, please let me know if that fully answers this problem.

Comment: this fully worked! Now I only got the problem that it's not showing in my inventory?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HUD.InventoryScript_ItemAdded (System.Object sender, InventoryEventArgs e) (at Assets/Scripts/HUD.cs:20)
Inventory.AddItem (IInventoryItem item) (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:30)
PlayerController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D hit) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:47)  
That's the error I'm having right now

Comment: @Cypher Include a screenshot showing the full hierarchy of the UI and the inspector with the UI gameobject selected. It looks like it can't find a gameobject named `InventoryPanel` among the children of UI

Comment: thank you so much! now the item dissapears in game and shows in inventory!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please be sure to upvote my answer and/or click the grey checkmark (✔) next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. This helps people who see this question on the search page see that it has an answer and it also gives me some reputation :)  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.